# How to remove 1 item in a list in Django?

Tags: html, django, django-views

This is the HTML code:

```
             <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-xl-2 text-center">
                {% if show_follow_button %}
                    <button id="follow-btn" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" name="follow" 
                        {% if already_follow %}disabled{% endif %}>
                        Follow
                    </button>
                    <button id="unfollow-btn" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" name="unFollow" 
                        {% if already_unFollow %}disabled{% endif %}>
                        Unfollow
                    </button>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
```

So I have 1 button each for following and unfollowing a user.
I'm trying to make the unfollow button remove that specific user in the list of users I've already followed.

In my views.py I have this code in 1 of my methods:

```
    show_follow_button = False
    if user_id is not None and user_id != request.user.id:
        show_follow_button = True

    already_follow = False
    already_unFollow = False
    if show_follow_button:
        already_follow = user_id in [x.user.id for x in UserExtended.objects.get(user__id=request.user.id).following.all()]
        already_unFollow = user_id in [x.user.id for x in UserExtended.objects.get(user__id=request.user.id).following.all().delete()]
```

I'm having a hard time making the last line of code work HAHA. Am confused. I don't know how to remove 1 loool. Help

Comment: No need to keep track of `already_unFollow`, in the html you can just do `not already_follow`

Comment: @RuudvandenBoomen is this it you mean?
                     ```<button id="unfollow-btn" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" name="unFollow" 
                        {% if not already_follow %}disabled{% endif %}>
                        Unfollow
                    </button>```

Comment: indeed, did that work for you :) ?

Comment: @RuudvandenBoomen there's no error but i cant seem to remove that 1 count from the total followed users' list.
```<button id="follow-btn" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" name="follow" 
                        {% if already_follow %}
                            disabled
                        {% elif not already_follow %}
                            enable
                        {% endif %}>
                        Follow/Unfollow
                    </button>```
I converted the button to this to make it like a toggle instead tho. xD

Comment: Still unsure how to remove that user from the list hmmm

Comment: You can do `UserExtended.objects.get(user__id=request.user.id).following.remove(user.id)`

Comment: I think I can use that. thanks so much.

Comment: Great, I will post the answer so u can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove a object from the list by doing:
`UserExtended.objects.get(user__id=request.user.id).following.remove(user.id)`